# Error when selecting 1 image from Intent Multiple

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I have a code below that works fine when selecting multiple image however if the image selected is only one it gave me an error. Here is the error

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1110896904, result=-1, data=Intent`

And here is the code

```
@SuppressLint("IntentReset")
    private fun checkAccessAndUpload() {
        if (context?.let {
                EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(
                    it,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                )
            } == true) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                var intent = Intent()
                intent.type = "image/*"
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
                intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
                startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture")
                    , PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE
                )
            } else {
                var intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
                intent.type = "image/*"
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE)
            }


        } else {
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
                this,
                "We need to access your camera and storage to upload your pictures",
                123,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            )
        }
    }


override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            val count = data.clipData!!.itemCount
            for (i in 0 until count) {
                var imageUri: Uri = data.clipData!!.getItemAt(i).uri
                ImageList.add(imageUri)
            }

            uploadImage()
        }

    }
```

The error happens here

`val count = data.clipData!!.itemCount`

How can I fix this error so my gallery intent can select 1 or multple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change code like this

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE  && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        if(data.clipData != null) {
            val count = data.clipData!!.itemCount
            for (i in 0 until count) {
                var imageUri: Uri = data.clipData!!.getItemAt(i).uri
                ImageList.add(imageUri)
            }
        }else if(data.data != null) {
            var imageUri: Uri = data.data!!
            ImageList.add(imageUri)
        }
        uploadImage()
    }

}
```

Comment: It gave me an error E/StorageException: No content provider: /document/image:6264 and when I check my firebase it uploads different picture after I select just one

Comment: change ' var imageUri: Uri = Uri.parse(data.data!!.path) '  to ' var imageUri: Uri = data.data!! '